# Count one column on another column

Tags: excel, excel-2007

**EDITED**

I am trying to count all values in column D/F when column B is "Started"/"Configured". This is what my data looks like.

```
B              D           F
Started        BARB1       BARB1
Started        BARB2
               BARB3       BARB2
Configured     BARB4
Started
```

I have tried the following formulas; (CountIf, SumProduct) But it just seems to count them in column B?

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$1800;B2="Started")
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$1800="Started")*($D$2:$CD$1800<>""))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version uses SUMPRODUCT so you don't need CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B$2:B$1800;{"started";"configured"};0))*(D$2:F$1800<>""))`

Comment: Oh interesting ;) Let me check this.

Comment: Works just as good and preferable because I don't need CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER! :D

Answer (score 1):

Forget what i wrote before, this IS the answer:

```
 {=SUM(IF((A:A="Started")*(D:D<>"");1;0))+SUM(IF((A:A="Configured")*(D:D<>"");1;0))}
```

(you know ctrl+shift+enter)

Comment: Damn, I forgot something in my question. That I got working, but with the edit that's the reason why I couldn't get it to work. Or I'm stupid as anything ...